# Reading Outlook email from other server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I want to read outlook emails from other server using my asp.net application. I am able to read outlook email from my system. I am using following code and I have also added reference of a dll Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. My code:-

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder mySend = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

int count = myInbox.Items.Count;
string sub = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[count]).Subject;
```

Please tell me the changes I need to make in my code so that I can read the outlook mail from other server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done, to use the Interop API you would need to have the Outlook installation on the same machine. Instead, you should look at reading directly from the Exchange server using the IMAP/POP protocols.

[MailSystem.NET](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) is a free library (open source) library which supports a variety of protocols (including IMAP4/POP3).

As per the comments, if you are running Exchange 2007 upwards the recommended way of reading emails is to use the [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

Comment: Can u tell me how can I read directly from Exchange server using the IMAP/POP protocols. Please help!!

Comment: @rahulaggarwal that's your job as a developer, the library I have recommended is a good place to start. Here is a [tutorial](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/reading-mails-using-imap-and-mailsystem-net/) that should help you on your way.

Comment: EWS (Exchange Web Services) is a much better alternative to POP3 or IMAP4 if you are accessing an Exchange Server.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I haven't used it, however, I do know that it's only supported by 2007 upwards, the OP didn't mention which version they were using. I will update for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BindData()
{ 
    OutLook._Application _app = new OutLook.Application();
    OutLook._NameSpace _ns = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    OutLook.MAPIFolder inbox = _ns.GetDefaultFolder(OutLook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    _ns.SendAndReceive(true);
    dt = new DataTable("Inbox");
    dt.Columns.Add("Sender", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Emails", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));        
    dt.Columns.Add("Body", typeof(string));
    int counter = 0;
    int noofemail = 0;
    for (counter = inbox.Items.Count; counter >= 1; counter--)
    {  OutLook.MailItem item = (OutLook.MailItem)inbox.Items[counter];           
            string Reply="";
            string ReplyAll = "";
            string Forward="";
            string Subject="";             
            Reply = string.Format("<a href = 'mailto:{1}' class='btn' style='color:white'>{0}</a>", "Reply", item.SenderEmailAddress);
            ReplyAll = string.Format("<a href = 'mailto:{1},{2}' class='btn' style='color:white'>{0}</a>", "ReplyAll", item.SenderEmailAddress, item.CC);
            Forward = string.Format("<a href = 'mailto:{1}' class='btn' style='color:white'>{0}</a>", "Forward", "");
            Subject = string.Format("<b><span style='color:#000000'>{0}</span></b><b style='float:right;color:#000000'>{1}</b><br><span style='color:#999999'>{2}</span>", item.SenderName, item.SentOn.ToLongTimeString(), item.Subject);           
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.SenderName,item.SenderEmailAddress,Subject, item.SentOn.ToLongDateString() + " " + item.SentOn.ToLongTimeString(), Reply, ReplyAll, Forward, item.HTMLBody });             
    }
    EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> rows = null;
    rows = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where row.Field<DateTime>("Date") > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
            orderby row["Date"] descending
            select row);
    dt.Rows.Add(rows);
   gvEmail.DataSource = dt;
   gvEmail.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: using OutLook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;                         need to add this as name space in your project and add referance outlook object

Comment: DO NOT DO THAT.. No Office app (including Outlook) can be used from a service (such as IIS).